# Suggest purchase a pet fish from a four-star online store?

Tags: aquarium, fish, freshwater, pet-selection, saltwater

Due to the currently pandemic we are in, one of my wife's friend gave us her fish tank and its supplies. We have two boys and they like fish.

I, myself, do not like Petco or Petsmart store that sells their pet fish. Their selection of fish is pretty limited to choose to buy.

What I would like to look for a **good online store that has a high marks from their customers**.

My wife would like to get goldfish, but I don't like them...

Do you have any suggestion? We live in Colorado.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Pets, I'm not really sure whether the current formulation of your question is the best fit for our site, since it could be seen by some people as opinion-based and not having the one, definitive answer. Nonetheless, I personally see positive value in the essence of your question and I think it could potentially be informative and useful for those interested. I couldn't directly answer your question because I'm living in different part of the world (Poland, Eastern Europe) - where, besides ...

Comment: ... bigger retail chains, there are lots of small, family pet stores and thus a lot of potential options to choose from, so I've never had a similar problem - I guess it's just different where I live. By the way, in case someone else decides that your question was not suitable for the Q&A site, I'm sure it will be welcome in [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box).

Comment: I assume it is not allowed to ask especially for stores. Like advertise it would be out of focus of this sites. But if you ask, how you could identify a good (online) pet store, then you will get good answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a lot better to buy fish from a local petshop, close to where you live. You can see the fish you buy and the shorter time it takes to bring the fish home from a shop will most likely stress the fish less, so their health will be better.

I understand why you try to avoid the large petshop chains, but it still might be better to get your fish there than it is to buy online.

If you buy fish online you risk the fish dying during transport if any delays happen (they DO), one does not know what stress the fish is exposed to during transport, like heat, cold or bumpy ride.

Most online shops will not send live fish as mail or cargo because the transport takes too long - even if the transport goes as planned, the transit time might be over 24 hours.

Goldfish grow too large for you to keep them in a fishtank, to keep one single goldfish you need a tank of 75 liters and for every additional fish you will have to add 50 liters in tank size. More details about goldfish could be found [at the relevant article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldfish) on Wikipedia.